# Random Reboot HP dv6t-se

Tags: laptop, shutdown

I've got an HP dv6t that's about 4 years old runs Win7 x64
All stock except an SSD installed a few months back.

Lately while in use it will shut down without warning. 
The screen will go black and the laptop will take a few seconds to wind down before the shutdown. 
This shutdown period leads me to believe it is not a power supply issue.

Occasionally instead of a full shutdown it appears to just be in sleep mode.

Internal temp was reaching up to 80C, however this issue still happens during boot after several hours rest (safe to assume room temp).

I've run a few virus checks that have all come back clean, and just to be sure it wasn't the SSD I put the old HDD back and it still happened.

That's pretty much everything I've tried, was hoping for an expert opinion. 
Ask questions as needed, I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I went in and cleaned out the vent, 80C was a max not a resting. Temp now rests around 45C. But still having the issue. I'll try cleaning those contacts and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

80ºC is dangerously, insanely, hot. Your CPU is probably shutting down to avoid cooking itself.

Is the fan clogged with dust? Take off the keyboard and clean out the fan and the vent. Taking keyboards off HPs is really easy, especially if you are careful not to disconnect the ribbon cable.   HP tells you how. http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03293129

Is something blocking the cooling airflow?  Take a look.

I upgraded an old HP laptop with a SSD a year or so ago. I had problems for a couple of months -- it wouldn't boot sometimes. I removed and inserted the drive a few times; that cleaned the disk drive connectors, and it's been working flawlessly ever since.